# Git make filename's first letter uppercase

Tags: macos, git, case-sensitive

I have a funny situation whereby I want to change a filename's first letter to be uppercase and then git commit that change.

```
$ mv filename.ext Filename.ext
$ git add Filename.ext
$ git commit -m "Made filename title case."
```

But git (at least on OSX) does not see the change of case as a change at all, so there is nothing to commit.

How can I change this file and commit that change?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is the HFS+ (the Mac's file system) is case insensitive.  You can try `git mv --force filename.ext Filename.ext`.